# use some default value in arithmetic operation if no row is found

Tags: mysql, database

I have got two tables:

```
booking(advertiser_id,  name, bookings, on_date)
click(advertiser_id, name, clicks, on_date)
```

I need to find `bookings/clicks` for each `name`, **advertiser_id-wise** and **date-wise**. I was doing the following to achieve this:

```
select b.name, b.advertiser_id, max(b.bookings)/max(c.clicks), b.on_date from click c inner join booking b on 
    c.advertiser_id = b.advertiser_id and 
    c.name = b.name and
    c.on_date = b.on_date
group by
    b.name,
    b.advertiser_id,
    b.on_date
```

I need to return 0, if there are no bookings (no entry in booking table) for that specific click. How can I achieve this?

Example:

`click` table:

```
name clicks on_date    advertiser_id
uk   123    2018-05-01 12
us   123    2018-05-02 12
us   123    2018-05-01 12
```

`booking` table:

```
advertiser_id name bookings on_date
12            uk   1200     2018-05-07 
12            us   123      2018-05-07
12            uk   123      2018-05-01
12            us   123      2018-05-01
```

Result:

```
name advertiser_id max(b.bookings)/max(c.clicks) on_date
uk   12            1.0000                        2018-05-01
us   12            1.0000                        2018-05-01
```

Expected:

```
name advertiser_id max(b.bookings)/max(c.clicks) on_date
uk   12            1.0000                        2018-05-01
us   12            1.0000                        2018-05-01
us   12            0                             2018-05-02
```

**Note**

I used `max` as to use columns which were not present in `group by`.

Comment: an advertiser can have his advertisement in different countries on different dates. there aren't any primary key in this case.

Comment: no problem!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to think about...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS click;

CREATE TABLE click
(name CHAR(2) NOT NULL
,clicks INT NOT NULL
,on_date DATE NOT NULL
,advertiser_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(name,on_date,advertiser_id)
);

INSERT INTO click VALUES
('uk',123,'2018-05-01',12),
('us',123,'2018-05-02',12),
('us',123,'2018-05-01',12);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS booking;

CREATE TABLE booking 
(advertiser_id INT NOT NULL
,name CHAR(2) NOT NULL
,bookings INT NOT NULL
,on_date DATE NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(advertiser_id,name,on_date)
);

INSERT INTO booking VALUES
(12,'uk',1200,'2018-05-07'),
(12,'us', 123,'2018-05-07'),
(12,'uk', 123,'2018-05-01'),
(12,'us', 123,'2018-05-01');


select c.name
     , c.advertiser_id
     , COALESCE(b.bookings,0)
     , c.clicks
     , c.on_date 
  from click c 
  left
  join booking b 
    on c.advertiser_id = b.advertiser_id 
   and c.name = b.name 
   and c.on_date = b.on_date;

+------+---------------+------------------------+--------+------------+
| name | advertiser_id | COALESCE(b.bookings,0) | clicks | on_date    |
+------+---------------+------------------------+--------+------------+
| uk   |            12 |                    123 |    123 | 2018-05-01 |
| us   |            12 |                    123 |    123 | 2018-05-01 |
| us   |            12 |                      0 |    123 | 2018-05-02 |
+------+---------------+------------------------+--------+------------+
```

Comment: i know about `coalesce`, but how to use it in arithmetic operation?

Comment: COALESCE(b.bookings/c.clicks,0) x

Comment: it returned result without the 3rd row

Comment: Plainly, that isn't true

Comment: i just ran it!!

Comment: `select b.name, b.advertiser_id, COALESCE(max(b.bookings)/max(c.clicks), 0), b.on_date from click c inner join booking b on 
    c.advertiser_id = b.advertiser_id and 
    c.name = b.name and
    c.on_date = b.on_date
group by
    b.name,
    b.advertiser_id,
    b.on_date`

Comment: That's not remotely similar to my query

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `LEFT JOIN`, So your query should look like,

```
select C.name,c.advertiser_id, IFNULL(max(b.bookings)/max(c.clicks), 0),c.on_date
FROM click c
LEFT join booking b on
   c.advertiser_id = b.advertiser_id and 
   c.name = b.name and
   c.on_date = b.on_date
group by
   b.name,
   b.advertiser_id,
   b.on_date
```

And it's working perfectly.

Open [LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88c1eba/1) to see the output.

Comment: yeah i was using outer join to solve this, thanks :)

Comment: the parameters in select and groupby are different so it was giving error on my system,  so i did: `select c.name,c.advertiser_id, IFNULL(max(b.bookings)/max(c.clicks), 0),c.on_date
FROM click c
LEFT join booking b on
   c.advertiser_id = b.advertiser_id and 
   c.name = b.name and
   c.on_date = b.on_date
group by
   c.name,
   c.advertiser_id,
   c.on_date`

Comment: so why you right on Strawberry's answer, not in my ?